# Google Maps API V3 Event

Tags: javascript, events, google-maps-api-3

I'm wanting this code

```
   google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: event.latLng
   }); 
      var outsideContent = "my content";
       infowindow.setContent(outsideContent);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
      });
```

to open an info window if the map is clicked where an overlay/polygon is not present. However, the code isn't executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a problem with the location where you have defined your map `click` listener, it is down inside the `generateInfoWindow` function, which only appears to get called from the `zoomtoaddress` function.

If you move that listener setup out next to where you create the map in the `intialize` function, I think you should be good with opening the `InfoWindow` when the map is clicked:

```
function initialize() {
    // ...
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), options);

    // Move your event listener definition right here:
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: event.latLng }); 
        var outsideContent = "outside content replaced for brevity";
        infowindow.setContent(outsideContent);    //include var name correction
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

    //the rest of initialize...
}
```

Also, if you want the marker you are creating in the event listener to display, you will have to pass the `map` property of the `MarkerOptions` as well. It looks like you may not want the marker to display, so I've left that out -

Comment: Sure, glad to help, but I'm looking at the code at your example link, and it includes the var name case problem. Just trying to help :) At any rate, I think the real root cause is the place where the map `click` event listener is being defined.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is case-sensitive.  infoWindow and infowindow refer to two different things.

```
infoWindow.setContent(outsideContent);
infowindow.open(map, marker);
```

Not sure this is actually your problem though (I'd expect to still see a blank infowindow).  Of course you don't need to have a marker to open an infowindow, e.g. check this blog post of mine showing [how to add an infowindow to a map in response to user clicks](http://duncan99.wordpress.com/2011/11/04/google-maps-api-adding-infowindows-in-response-to-user-clicks/).

In theory this should work for you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.820645,-0.137376),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var infowindow =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: 'my content'
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        infowindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
        infowindow.open(map);
    }); 
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

The problems might stem from any other event listeners you have, and possibly the KML layers you've got going on.

Comment: Thanks, @duncan. That was just a typo in the post..the code was correct (or at least properly capitalized).